# Swift - Displaying different versions of view controller to certain type of user

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Trying to follow some best practices so looking for suggestions.

Have 2 types of users: user, admin

And want to present a different “version” of a particular view controller to certain user types.  This particular view controller is nested into a tab bar controller, and the other view controllers in the tab bar controller will be the same for each user.

Possibly overthinking this, and thought about going the the route of hiding storyboard elements based on user type, but there must be a better way to accomplish presenting different versions of a view controller nested in a tab bar controller.

Comment: [Use a container view setup to support multiple child view controllers](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&ei=8cydW5OHGISj8QXcsoX4DQ&q=swift+container+view+multiple+view+controllers&oq=swift+container+view+with+m&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i22i30k1.13307.16461.0.17769.11.9.2.0.0.0.567.1656.2-1j1j0j2.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..6.5.1097...33i22i29i30k1.0.7Cq2w0ghlzc)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create two different `ViewControllers` and segue to the correct one based on the user type.

If you start at `InitialViewController`, then create two different segues that go to `AdminViewController` and `UserViewController`. Afterwards, perform the type-checking in `InitialViewController` and segue accordingly to the correct one.

There are a lot of other ways to overcome your problem. If you need any further clarification or a different way of doing so, do not hesitate commenting!

Comment: Thx for the suggestion and decided to essentially what you said, but with a copy and paste of all my VCs for the user type and editing for admin type with a segue to direct to the correct vc "set".  There will be more editing bwn the VCs for each type than I had thought so makes more sense to go down this route.

Comment: The two different `ViewControllers` you declare can afterwards segue to the same flow of ViewControllers, this way you don't have to copy and paste all subsequent view controllers. I would also suggest wrapping the common code between `AdminViewController` and `UserViewController` in a superclass `BaseUserViewController` so that you don't have to write the same repetitive code multiple times, then inherit from `BaseUserViewController` to both `AdminViewController` and `UserViewController`.

Comment: If you went for my solution, I would also highly appreciate it if you could mark it as the correct one @Ben